# How to check if git.Repo().remotes.origin.pull() actually updated the directory with new code/files

Tags: python, gitpython

```py
import git # gitpython module
def update_repo(repo)
    repo = git.Repo(repo)
    ret = repo.remotes.origin.pull()
    print(ret)
    # some code I want to execute if and only if repo.remotes.origin.pull() changed something within the directory
update_repo('/Path/To/Repo/.git')
>>> [<git.remote.FetchInfo object at 0x7f83521b21b0>]
```

I tried printing what `repo.remotes.origin.pull()` returns and got a list of `git.remote.FetchInfo` object. I searched it up, and found a reference of this in their documentation [git.remote.FetchInfo](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.remote.FetchInfo) but I quite don't understand if anything in there would help me with what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading the documentation over and over again, I finally realized that `git.remote.FetchInfo.flags` gave me an integer depending on the action of the pull

after a bit testing, I found out that if the `flag == 4` then no files whereas `flag == 64` means that there was a change

```py
def update_repo(repo)
    repo = git.Repo(repo)
    ret = repo.remotes.origin.pull()
    print(ret)
    if ret[0].flags == 4:
        return
    # rest of the code I wanted to execute only if a change took place
```

Comment: You don't want an "== 4" but rather a "has bit 2 set" (`(ret[0] & 4) != 0`). Don't use the magic number 4 either; use the name `HEAD_UPTODATE` (from whatever namespace it resides in). This is a "flags word" because *more than one flag may be set*.